# Запретить управление программой из консоли js

Tags: javascript, консоль

Добрый день! Столкнулась с проблемой есть код секундомера который работает исправно, но необходимо, что бы им нельзя было управлять с консоли(вызывать разные методы, удалять их, задавать новые, т.д), как можно ограничить доступ из вне программы? Также скажите, пожалуйста, как можно избежать скачущего счетчика (когда запускается при смене цифр счетчик скачет). Заранее благодарна.

```
function Stopwatch (elem) {
    var time = 0;
    var interval;
    var offset;

    function update() { 
        if (this.isOn) {
            time += delta();
        }

        var timeFormatted = timeFormat(time);
        elem.innerHTML = timeFormatted;
    }

    function delta() { // ф-ция вычисляет сколько времени прошло
        var now = Date.now();
        var timePassed = now - offset;
        offset = now;
        return timePassed;
    }

    function timeFormat(timeInMilSeconds) {
        var milSec = time % 1000;
        var sec = Math.floor(time/1000);
        var min = Math.floor(time/(1000*60));
        var hours = Math.floor(time/(1000*60*60));

      if ( hours < 10) {
        hours =  '0' + hours; 
      }

      if (min >= 60) {
        min = min % 60;
      }

      if (min < 10) {
        min = '0' + min;
      }

      if (sec >= 60) {
        sec = sec % 60;
      }

      if ( sec < 10) {
        sec = '0' + sec;
      }

      if (milSec < 100) {
        milSec = '0' + milSec;
      }

      return hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec + '.' + milSec;

    }

    this.running = false;

    this.startPause = function() {
        if ( !this.isOn) {
          document.getElementById('startPause').innerHTML = 'Pause';
          interval = setInterval( update.bind(this), 1);
          offset = Date.now(); // время запуска секундомера
          this.isOn = true;

        } else {
            document.getElementById('startPause').innerHTML = 'Resume';
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = 0;
            this.isOn = false;
        }
    }

     this.reset = function(){
        time = 0;
        document.getElementById('startPause').innerHTML = 'Start';

        update();
     }
 }



var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
var startFunc = document.getElementById('startPause');
var resetFunc = document.getElementById('reset');

var watch = new Stopwatch(timer);

startFunc.addEventListener('click', function(){
    watch.startPause();
});

resetFunc.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if ( watch.isOn ){
        watch.startPause();
        watch.reset();

    } else {
        watch.reset();
    }   
});
```

Comment: Привяжите данный счетчик ко времени сервера, и тогда пусть меняют сколько угодно, действие все ровно исполниться только когда действительно пройдет нужное время. Предположу что у вас по окончанию времени должно что то произойти, а пользователь взял и сменил время на ноль, в таком случае если счетчик time <= 0 то пошел ajax запрос к серверу, где сервер даст точное время, и вернет его клиенту, ну а ваш скрипт вновь сверит time > 0 тогда time = time.server. Прошу сильно не пинать за коммент, так как я не совсем понял для чего это вам надо )) Ну а запретить пользоваться консолью нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

1) никак. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21693931/5006740

2) я просто отредактирую отсылаемые на сервер поля, в смысле, сделаю свой запрос

Comment: когда запускается счётчик цифры "прыгают" слегка.

Comment: обновил, добавили бы исходный html-код для элемента с id 'startPause'

Comment: `<div id="timer"  class="stopwatch timer"> 00:00:00.000</div>
     <button id="startPause" class="btn start ">Start</button>
     <button id="reset" class="btn stop">Reset</button>` вот html-код

Comment: я бы попробовал менять button.value, а не innerhtml, плюс, тут все зависит еще и от браузера. конкретно в этом вопросе я вам помочь не смогу. и да, исходник html лучше в вопрос перенести из комментов